# Prove that $(\cap\cup\langle x,y\rangle) \bigcup \bigl((\cup\cup\langle x,y\rangle ) \setminus (\cup\cap\langle x,y\rangle)\bigr) = y$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$\langle x,y \rangle$ is a Kuratowski pair.
Prove that
$$\Bigl(\cap\cup\langle x,y \rangle\Bigr) \bigcup 
\Bigl((\cup\cup\langle x,y \rangle)\setminus(\cup\cap\langle x,y \rangle)\Bigr)=y$$

Comment: I guess by [Kuratowski pair](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair#Kuratowski_definition) you mean $\{ \{ x \},  \{ x,  y \} \}$, right?

Comment: Just write out the elements in the unions/intersections. For example, $\cap \cup \langle x,y \rangle = \cap \{x,y\} = x \cap y$.

Comment: Yes, that`s what I meant.

Comment: What have you tried? It's not a very hard exercise. You just need to unfold the definitions.

Comment: It was very easy indeed, just unfolding the definitions.

Comment: You should, if so, write an answer to your own question and if it is indeed correct you can accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that $$\begin{align*}
\cup\langle x,y\rangle &= \cup\{ \{x\},\{x,y\}\}=  \{x\}\bigcup\{x,y\} = \{x,y\}\\
\cap\langle x,y\rangle &= \cap\{ \{x\},\{x,y\}\} = \{x\}\bigcap\{x,y\}=\{x\}.
\end{align*}$$

So 
$$\begin{align*}
\cap\cup\langle x,y\rangle &= \cap\{x,y\} = x\cap y,\\
\cup\cap\langle x,y\rangle &= \cup\{x\} = x,\\
\cup\cup\langle x,y\rangle &= \cup\{x,y\} = x\cup y.
\end{align*}$$

Things should be rather easy now.